# ASP.NET Core Identity Navbar Layout not rendering correctly

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm creating my first ASP.NET Core MVC project which could be used by (Dutch) companies to rent rooms/apartments.

I had my project set up first with 2 databaseContexts, 1 named AuthDBContext which stored the user information, and 1 database context under Core named DatabaseContext.

Everything was working fine until I had to add Authorization to the project. Since the users and the data were stored in different DBcontexts, I thought it would be easier to merge these 2 contexts.

I did this by manually copying all the files from the Areas folder to the Core folder in which I created the same folders. I changed all the references to Area/Areas to Core with the help of the search function and after some time I succeeded in making the login work again and store all the data in 1 context.

but the problem was that once I pressed the login or register button the styling of the navbar would disappear and the name of my project in the upper left-hand corner was displaying dat instead of the project name.

This is the correct Navbar:

[image]

this is the incorrect Navbar:

[image]

if I return to the Homepage without logging in the styling is back to normal, when I log on and go to any of the pages that don't involve the login or register the navbar is styled correctly (for example going to Home/Index, Gebouw/Index or Kamer/Index) but if I go to any of the pages associated with Authentication the navbar doesn't get correct styling.

I've checked a previous version of the project where the styling was correct and changed all the Layout references to match the correct files.

This are the files in which I reference Layout, File `/Verhuurlijst/Core/identity/Pages/Account/manage/_Layout.cshtm`

```
@{
if (ViewData.TryGetValue("ParentLayout", out var parentLayout))
    {
        Layout = (string)parentLayout;
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
}
```

- /Verhuurlijst/Core/identity/Pages/ViewStart.cshtml:

  `@{ Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }`
- /Views/ViewStart.cshtml:

  `@{ Layout = "_Layout"; }`

I tried making my own _Layout page in the folder Core/Identity/Pages/ and copy the content of the /Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml in there and changed the reference in the Manage/_Layout file to - Verhuurlijst/Core/identity/Pages/Account/manage/_Layout.cshtm:

```
@{
    if (ViewData.TryGetValue("ParentLayout", out var parentLayout))
    {
        Layout = (string)parentLayout;
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "/Core/Identity/Pages/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
}
```

but that didn't change anything, I've tried referencing the /Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml file in the Login and register pages but that didn't change anything either.

I tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding one, clearing the cache multiple times, changing the code in Core/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/_Layout.cshtml to simply use `Layout = /Views/shared/_Layout` instead of the if/else block. but nothing seems to work.

In the debugger, no errors are generated when loading the application or pages.

I've been stuck on this problem for over 6 hours and I'm lost on how to solve this problem.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Via the following link you can access the Project:
https://github.com/GillesDeLeus/Verhuur.git

I tried to add the original source control link but since this was password protected by my organization I wasn't able to share the direct link, instead I compressed the files and added them to a new repo.
The file compressed was too big so I had to split it into different packets. hopefully, this doesn't create any problems.

If anyone needs some more information, source code, or anything feel free to ask, I'll be checking this post multiple times per day to provide any needed information.

update:
In my Verhuurlijst.csproj I found

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>false</CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>
    <UserSecretsId>639ee4f0-8e5c-4a28-b85c-9b133d303b57</UserSecretsId>
    <AssemblyName>dat</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DataTables-Editor-Server" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="jQuery" Version="3.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="jquery.datatables" Version="1.10.15" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook" Version="5.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google" Version="5.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="5.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="X.PagedList.Mvc.Core" Version="8.0.7" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Migrations\AuthDB\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

that's the only reference I found in the entire solution, I did notice that when I start the project the window gives me the following path:
[PathDebugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhVUd.png)

When I change the assembly name the project won't open anymore and I get an error message:[ErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bB8JO.png)

The only other reference to assembly is in the IdentityHostingStartup file:

```
[assembly:HostingStartup(typeof(Verhuurlijst.Core.Identity.IdentityHostingStartup))]
namespace Verhuurlijst.Core.Identity
{
    public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                        context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Main")));


            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `dat` in your navbar?Is somewhere include `dat` in your project?The navbar is in `Views/Shared/ _LoginPartial.cshtml` by default.And you can see `<partial name="_LoginPartial" />` in `<header></header>` of _Layout.cshtml.You can check `_LoginPartial.cshtml`.

Comment: in the login partial there is no reference to Layout but even when I add one it doesn't change anything for the navbar, I can style the words login or register in the navbar but not the whole navbar